# How to convert date input to a timestamp in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time

Is there a way to convert this date input `01 Nov 2020, 9:55pm +10:00` to a timestamp like this `2020-11-01T11:55:00Z`?

Comment: Just `new Date("01 Nov 2020, 9:55pm +10:00").toISOString()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment lib.

sample:

```
const moment = require("moment");

const inputDate = "01 Nov 2020, 9:55pm +10:00";
const formatedDate = moment(inputDate, "DD MMM YYYY, HH:mmA ZZ");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `new Date("01 Nov 2020, 9:55 pm +10:00").toISOString()`

NOTE: make sure that `9:55` and `PM` are separated

```js
const date = new Date("01 Nov 2020, 9:55 pm +10:00").toISOString()

console.log(date)
```